# React this.setState issue

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am working on a React app. I am getting a json data and sorting by randomizing the data inside the array. Whenever I use this.setState, the state is being updated and changing the initial order of my json data as well. The question is how to update state without interfering the JSON data? Here is my code if it helps:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { test } from "./test.json";
import swal from 'sweetalert';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Nav from "./Nav";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { index: 0, result: 0, testLength: test.length, test: test };
    let result = 1;
  }

  getTest() {
    return this.state.test
      .sort((a, b) => {
        return 0.5 - Math.random();
      })
      .map((item, i) => {
        if (i == 0) {
          return (
            <section key={i} className="d-flex main-sec">
              <h3>{item.question}</h3>
              <form className="list-group form">
                {item.answer
                  .sort((a, b) => {
                    return 0.5 - Math.random();
                  })
                  .map((item, i) => {
                    return (
                      <li key={i} className="list-group-item test-list list-group-item-action">
                        <input
                          type="radio"
                          name="answer"
                          value={item.isTrue}
                          onClick={this.onChange.bind(this)}
                        />
                        <p>{item.ans}</p>
                      </li>
                    );
                  })}
              </form>
              <button className="pre-button btn btn-lg btn-danger" onClick={this.prevEl.bind(this)}>
                <i className="fa fa-long-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"/> Prev
              </button>
              <button className="next-button btn btn-lg btn-success" onClick={this.nextEl.bind(this)}>
                Next <i className="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true" />
              </button>
            </section>
          );
        } else if(i == this.state.testLength - 1) {
            return (
              <section key={i} className="d-none">
              <h3>{item.question}</h3>
              <form className="list-group form">
                {item.answer
                  .sort((a, b) => {
                    return 0.5 - Math.random();
                  })
                  .map((item, i) => {
                    return (
                      <li key={i} className="list-group-item test-list list-group-item-action">
                        <input
                          type="radio"
                          name="answer"
                          value={item.isTrue}
                          onClick={this.onChange.bind(this)}
                        />
                        <p>{item.ans}</p>
                      </li>
                    );
                  })}
              </form>
              <button className="pre-button btn btn-lg btn-danger" onClick={this.prevEl.bind(this)}>
                <i className="fa fa-long-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"/> Prev
              </button>
              <div id="check-result">
                <button className="pre-button btn btn-lg btn-success" onClick={this.prevEl.bind(this)}>
                  Check Your Result
                </button>
              </div>
            </section>
            )
        }else {
          return (
            <section key={i} className="d-none">
              <h3>{item.question}</h3>
              <form className="list-group form">
                {item.answer.map((item, i) => {
                  return (
                    <li key={i} className="list-group-item test-list list-group-item-action">
                      <input
                        type="radio"
                        name="answer"
                        value={item.isTrue}
                        onClick={this.onChange.bind(this)}
                      />
                      <p>{item.ans}</p>
                    </li>
                  );
                })}
              </form>
              <button className="pre-button btn btn-lg btn-danger" onClick={this.prevEl.bind(this)}><i className="fa fa-long-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true" /> Prev</button>
              <button className="pre-button btn btn-lg btn-success" onClick={this.nextEl.bind(this)}>Next <i className="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true" /></button>
            </section>
          );
        }
      });
  }

  onChange(e) {
    const currEl = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
    const result = document.getElementById("result");
    currEl.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(item => {
      return item.setAttribute("disabled", true);
    });
    const currElclicked = e.target.value;

    if (currElclicked == "true") {
      e.target.parentElement.className = "list-group-item test-list list-group-item-action right";
      console.log(result.textContent);
      result.innerHTML = parseInt(result.textContent) + 1;
    } else {
      e.target.parentElement.className = "list-group-item test-list list-group-item-action wrong";
      currEl.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(item => {
        if (item.value == "true") {
          item.parentElement.className = "list-group-item test-list list-group-item-action right";
        }
      });
    }
  }

  prevEl(e) {
    const currEl = e.target.parentElement;
    const preEl = e.target.parentElement.previousSibling;
    if (preEl && preEl.nodeName === "SECTION") {
      currEl.className = "d-none";
      preEl.className = "d-flex main-sec";
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }

  nextEl(e) {
    const currEl = e.target.parentElement;
    const nextEl = e.target.parentElement.nextSibling;
    const currElForm = currEl.querySelectorAll("form");
    const isChecked = currElForm[0].querySelectorAll("input:checked");
    console.log(isChecked)
    console.log(this.result)
    if (isChecked.length != 0) {
      if (nextEl && nextEl.nodeName === "SECTION") {
        currEl.className = "d-none";
        nextEl.className = "d-flex main-sec";
        this.setState({index: this.state.index+1})
      } else {
        console.log("wrong");
        return;
      }
    } else {
      swal("To'xtang!", "Javoblardan birini tanlang", "error");
      return;
    }
  }
  render() {
    let result = 0;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1><span id="result">
          {result}</span>
        </h1>
        {this.getTest()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please cut this down to a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Don't perform the randomised sorting in `render` if you do not want a new order when it re-renders.

Instead sort the json data when you receive it initially.

Comment: are suggesting to randomize and store it in state? If so I also have to sort another array within array. i think it is a bit complicated

Comment: sure I will try. But my concern is I have this data `{ test:[{question: "something", ans: [1,2,3]}] } ` and I have to randomize both questions and answers.

Comment: I wrote a sorting function and it is working just fine. Here is the code
    `componentDidMount() {
         let newArr = [];
         test.sort((a, b) => 0.5 - Math.random()).map(i => {
             return newArr.push({
                                 question: i.question,
                                 answer: i.answer.sort((a, b) => 0.5 - 
                                Math.random())
                      });
      });
    return this.setState({ testData: newArr });
  }`

Comment: if ur data fetch is async, `componentDidMount` is where you should do it. If you are importing it from a json file like ur code above, you should do the sorting in the constructor to avoid an unnecessary re-render.